# inconsistent speeds from different services. Mainly speedtest.net

Tags: linux, networking, network-speed

I have had a few dedicated servers from online.net and they have all been great. But recently I have found issues with my connections on my new server. 
It is a Dedibox MD SSD 2015 Gen2 (Ubuntu 16.04).
The issues I can see that are baffling are a speedtest from speedtest.net looks like:

```
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 107.05 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed....................................................................................................
Upload: 3.94 Mbit/s
```

A upload to the likes of S3 can be about 80MB/s

and online ping test looks like:

```
iperf -c ping.online.net
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to ping.online.net, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 85.0 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local xx.xx.xx.xx port 48026 connected with xx.xx.xx.xx port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  1.10 GBytes   942 Mbits/sec
```

Also a test file from thinkbroadband looks like this:

```
wget http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/1GB.zip
--2017-01-14 22:49:53--  http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/1GB.zip
Resolving ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com (ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com)... 80.249.106.10
Connecting to ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com (ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com)|80.249.106.10|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1073741824 (1.0G) [application/zip]
Saving to: ‘1GB.zip’


1GB.zip                                             100%[=================================================================================================================>]   1.00G  57.2MB/s    in 18s     


2017-01-14 22:50:14 (56.9 MB/s) - ‘1GB.zip’ saved
```

As you can see these are strange results? Mainly the speedtest.net results.

Any help on what could be causing this issue would be grateful.

Comment: Would it make sense to contact your hosting provider?

Comment: Yes I have contacted the providers, but I am sure they will say it is a software problem, rather than an issue with the hardware